# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'load'

Tags: json, python-3.x

Reading json file in python in the following ways gives the error.

```
json=open('file.json')

data = json.load(json)   OR

with open("data_file.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
```

Both gives `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'load'`. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't call you're variable as `json`. This caused the mistake.

Do something like:

```
import json

not_json = open('file.json')
data = json.load(not_json)
```

Or even better:

```
with open('file.json') as input_file:
    data = json.load(input_file)
```

[edit]

To address to what commented below, when you declare something like:

```
import json

json = 2
```

the word `json` now points to a number , and you lose the name of the imported package. This is true **unless you declare it in a different scope** (inside a function for example).

**Best practice**: Try to avoid naming vars / function / classes etc in names which are built-ins, known packages etc (like: `list = 2; list([1,2,3])`)

Comment: To be a bit more complete: when doing `import json; json = open("file.json")`, the second statement rebinds the name "json" to the opened file (_io.TextIOWrapper) object, so you `json.load(...)` now searches for a `json` method on the file object. As a general rule: since in Python everything (including modules, classes and functions) is an object, there are no distinct namespaces for modules, functions, classes and other variables.